# PDF, Firefox and other browser don't hold css layout. IE only does

Tags: html, css, pdf, layout

I have a problem with html code. It's layout is supported only by IE and is displayed there as I wanted. However in PDF or other browser it is displayed badly. My -ms-grid is not holding its position.
Here is an screen of good layout:

[image]

and here is the screen of bad layout:

[image]

How can I fix my layout? Thanks for any help.

Comment: see screen under URL. I forgot to add description

Comment: Show some codes will helpful.

Comment: code is below. Its only part of it. First part is the post below.